# full calendar Show more events that are coming from javascript and show those events

Tags: javascript

Please follow the link:

http://access.spruceindustries.com/facility360/calendar-view.jsp

See my image, I want to reload the calendar when some one selects years, months, weeks and days. On clicking days from the javascript it returns dates, and that dates I want to show in the small full calendar.

When I click on the reference tab:

```
$('#recurrence').click(function(){
    if($('#checking_tab_2').val()=='off'){
        var insertEvents = {};
        insertEvents = {
            start: new Date(),
        }
        proposedEvents.push(insertEvents);

        console.log(proposedEvents);
        $('#mini_here').fullCalendar({
            header : {
                left : 'prev',
                center : 'title',
                right : 'next'
            },
            dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
            events: proposedEvents,
            eventRender: function(event, eventElement, view){
                var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                $('#mini_here .fc-bg .fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#87B87F');
            },
        });
    }
    $('#checking_tab_2').val('on');
});
```

But After click on the all the options(years, months, weeks, and days)

I want to reload the calendar and want to show the dates in the small calendar.

I tried with

```
$('#mini_here').html("");
$('#mini_here').fullCalendar({
    header : {
        left : 'prev',
        center : 'title',
        right : 'next'
    },
    dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    events: proposedEvents,
    eventRender: function(event, eventElement, view ){
        var dateString = moment(event.start).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        $('#mini_here .fc-bg .fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#87B87F');
    },
});
});
```

But It returns blank. I am using latest version of full calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the questions.

To add the more events again on full calendar, first we have to call destroy method and then render method. after that you can add your events that is coming from javascript.

Links are below : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/destroy/
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/

thanks.